# JavaFx and Facebook

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create an image editor with javafx. Is there any posibility to connect with facebook. I mean, after I modify a picture, how can it be posted on the facebook profile. Is there some library which can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [facebook graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview).

[Here you can find a java wrapper for it.](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Could u help me with something else ? I am trying to create this image editor, but i still have issues at the UI; I don't know how to set an image, uploaded with filechooser inside the borderpane(center).

Comment: I do not really understand what you are talking about, but if adding an ```Image``` to the ```BorderPane``` is what you are having trouble with, use an ```ImageView```